# How to retrive image from image path in MySQL databse table using jsp?

Tags: mysql, jsp

I want to display the image on a jsp. I have the image path in the MySQL table where the image is uploaded or stored. Using that image path how can I display the image on the JSP?. Can anyone show me the code for the same?

Comment: can you elaborate your question please ?

Comment: i want to display the image on a jsp. I have the image path in the MySql table where the image is uploaded or stored. Using that image path how can i display the image on the JSP??

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Showing your code and work goes a long way here to getting solid answers.

Comment: Since you already stored an image path (a unique image name) into the database, you just need `<img src="path/to/image">` on JSP pages.

Answer (score 0):

You get your jsp to emit an image tag.

For example, if your `imagepath` column contains `/assets/2015/abc123.jpg`, you arrange for the web page your jsp is serving to contain a tag like this:

```
<img src="//static.example.com/assets/2015/abc123.jpg">
```

Then, when the browser goes to render the page your jsp sent out, it will fetch the image from the path.

Now, I am guessing at the rules you need to follow to turn the path in your column into a valid URL. The business about `//static.example.com/` is my guess.  But that is the basic idea.

Comment: The purpose of a jsp is to write the contents of a web page as text. The `<img` tag is text like that.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there is an image stored in database as **images/triangle.gif** and in your project there is an *image* name **triangle.gif** under **web/images** folder. Then you can simply show the image like this.

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/triangle.gif">
```